# Question about linear machine learning models, positive coefficients, correlated features, and overfitting

Tags: regression, correlation, scikit-learn, overfitting

I am experimenting with a few different linear models from SKLearn. I am using a dataset with about 600 features and 350,000 samples. I have noticed that I get extreme overfitting unless I force the coefficients to be positive. Once I force coefficients to be positive I get a good match between in-sample and out of sample performance.

There is high correlation between the features, with many pairs above 0.7 measured by spearman correlation.

So my questions is whether the overfitting is due to the correlated features? Somehow when the algorithm is able to subtract two highly correlated features its able to overfit, but when it can only add them together it can't?

Answer (score 1):

> So my questions is whether the overfitting is due to the correlated features?

Doubtful.  Correlated features affect the stability of the coefficients, not the predictions.

What kinds of models are you using?  You have nigh 3 orders of magnitude more observations than variables, and so there should not be much over fitting from a linear model unless you're taking tons of pairwise interactions.

Comment: I have tried just regular OLS, lasso and ELasticNet.  Somehow they are able to overfit like you would expect of XGBoost... What do you mean pairwise interactions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be possible.  Consider an extreme case where $x_1$ and $x_2$ come from the same data generating process but with independent noise terms.  And suppose $y=x_1+\epsilon$.  Then any model of the form $\hat{y}=\alpha x_1 + (1-\alpha)x_2$ is "correct", but by having the flexibility to choose $\alpha$, your model will select the one that best fits the additional noise.  By constraining to nonnegative coefficients, you constrain $\alpha\in[0,1]$, limiting the flexibility.

In this simple example that shouldn't lead to worse performance on unseen data (the model is "correct" after all), but I suspect a cleverer example could do it; maybe just with many features of a similar flavor, you give your model enough room to fit to some randomly present trend in the noise of the training set that isn't present in the test set?  On the other hand, your dataset size is large enough that I'm surprised you'd see such extreme overfitting just from this sort of effect, if the test set is randomly drawn.